# Columns lining up with content

Tags: html, css, view, columnsorting, dynamic-columns

I have come across a problem, I can only use CSS and HTML. But for this I will give a basic layout that I have found.

The plan is to use this code instead of making the columns with (Min-height) (Height) on each div class, I was wondering if there could be a way of writing some CSS code that does that for you. It also needs to work in Mobile View, when in this view the columns should stack above one another.

If anyone could help me with this that would be great!!!!!

```css
.border-thinlight {
  border: 0.5rem solid #ffffff;
}

.bg-rboffwhite {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 3%;
}

.col {
  border: none;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page" style="font-family: 'lato',helvetica;">
  <div class="row border-thinlight">
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</div>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="row border-thinlight">
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.<br /><br />
      <center>
        <img src="https://image.petmd.com/files/styles/863x625/public/2022-10/Dachshund.jpeg" width="400px" height="250px" /></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers Adam, Still getting used to this website for help

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear as to what you want to achieve though. If you could explain a bit more, that would be appreciated.

Comment: So I have got some images and text within a page which aren't lining up, But I have found some code that makes them line up on each media platform. So instead of using min-heights and heights within the HTML, I was wondering if there is anything in the CSS that could make the columns all line up and also include all the content in them.

Comment: So do you want all the columns to be the same height, the same width or both?  Or do you want each column to line up with the one below it?

Comment: I want the columns the same height and width. But what ever is included in the columns shouldn't effect the column. I forgot to mention that it must be able to stack in mobile view also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your row class to grid (just so it's a bit more descriptive) but added the `grid-template-columns` property to `repeat(3, 1fr)`. This basically says 'create 3 columns and make them all the same width'.

I've then added the `grid-auto-rows` property and set this to 1fr. This makes all the rows the same height. Finally removed the width and height attributes from the image and added the `img` selector to your CSS and set the image width to 100% so it is the full width of the container and scales up and down as the browser window is resized.

To make them stack on top of each other, I've set the `grid-template-columns` property to just 1fr which is basically telling the browser that, at small screen sizes, you just want one column.

Have a look and if it's not exactly what you're looking to achieve pop a comment below.

```css
.border-thinlight {
  border: 0.5rem solid #ffffff;
}

.bg-rboffwhite {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 3%;
}

.col {
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page" style="font-family: 'lato',helvetica;">
  <div class="grid border-thinlight">
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.<br /><br />
      <img src="https://image.petmd.com/files/styles/863x625/public/2022-10/Dachshund.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-rboffwhite" style="padding: 1vw;">6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```